# On atlite, Can I configure the inlet and outlet temperature of the HTF for the CSP model? Or the average operating temperature?

Tags: pypsa

Using atlite, can I configure the inlet and outlet temperature of the HTF for the CSP model? Or the average operating temperature?

I would like to change variables and see the effect on the results.

I could not find any parameters on the csp function:

```
csp(cutout, installation, technology=None, **params)
```